# Iphone access a property value from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to access a property value of AppDelegate class  from someView Controller without creating reference of the delegate in view controller?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean - there are multiple ways to get information from your application delegate into a view controller, and the phrase "without creating reference of the delegate" is unclear. Your options basically are:

1. Reference the application delegate, casting as appropriate. You would write code in your view controller class like:

   ```
   id propertyValue = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myProperty];
   ```
2. Pass the property in when creating the view controller. This requires the view controller to have a `@property` declared and `@synthesize`d for use, then you would have the app delegate just set the property on the view controller instance.

Neither of these options require that you retain a copy of your app's delegate as a `@property`, but the first does reference the delegate once.

Comment: One more question [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; Is this a standrad  way , why Am asking is I need a property called "sharedObject" in 3 different class files , "sharedObject" resides in AppDelegate class ?

Comment: Unless you want to create a singleton class to house the property, using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` is the standard way to access that property among multiple classes. (And let's be honest; you're basically accessing a singleton anyway. No need to multiply singletons.)

Answer (score 20):

[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate

You'll also need to include the app delegate header file in your view controller and possibly typecast the delegate from id to your actual app delegate class.

```
#include "MyAppDelegate.h"

((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).myProperty;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: Am looking for alternative way to achieve the same besides doing [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;. 1. Something like accessing the value through publish/subscribe? 2. One more question [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; Is this a standrad , way why Am asking is I need property called "sharedObject" in 3 different class files , "sharedObject" resides in AppDelegate class ?