# Accessing AppDelegate Property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to pass a string to all my other view controllers from the `AppDelegate`. I have defined a variable called `appName` and assign it a string

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appName;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize appName;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    appName=@"SatKacPara";
    return YES;
}
```

The following implementation does not have access to `appName` property. I could not able to figure out.

**ViewController1.m**

```
appLabel.text=[(AppDelegate*) [UIApplication shareApplication].delegate ].appName;
```

[image]

Comment: Why not put it in a constants file then? It isn't appropriate to be in the app delegate...

Comment: `((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).appName`!?

Comment: You mean the [sharedApplication function](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplication/sharedApplication) right? It seems you have a typo.

Comment: Why add a property for the app name? You can easily get the app's display name directly from the Info.plist. Use the `infoDictionary` property of `NSBundle`. Use the `CFBundleDisplayName` key. With this you don't need to update any code if you change the app's name or localize it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175878/iphone-access-a-property-value-from-appdelegate?rq=1

Comment: FYI - there is no need for the `@synthesize` line. That's quite outdated in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your line of code. It should be:

```
appLabel.text = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).appName;
```

But using such a property isn't necessary. You can get the app's display name without hardcoding it.

Get rid of your `appName` property and change this line of code to:

```
appLabel.text = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

This has the advantage of showing the right name even if you rename your app or localize it.

Comment: even your answer contains the same typo . It should be ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).appName;

Comment: @Mr.T That's the same thing I have in my answer. What are you talking about? I changed the outer square brackets to parentheses, just like you did in your comment.

Comment: i mean shareApplication should be sharedApplication :)

Comment: @Mr.T Aha. I did miss that. I got focused on the brackets. Fixed and thanks.