# Check if method/property in AppDelegate exists

Tags: c#, ios, reflection, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I try to find out if the `AppDelegate` contains a certain property/method. For this I found [Check if a property exist in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341028/check-if-a-property-exist-in-a-class) and [How to check whether an object has certain method/property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114469/how-to-check-whether-an-object-has-certain-method-property), but the `AppDelegate` seems to be different.

The following will not compile

```
if(AppDelegate.HasMethod("SomeMethod"))
```

because

> AppDelegate does not contain a defintion for `HasMethod`.

I also tried other variations but I didn't get it managed to successfully check if the method/property exists or not. Furthermore `respondsToSelector` seems not to be applicable here. `GetType()` is also not available for `AppDelegate`.

What is the correct way for checking if a property/method in `AppDelegate` exists?

**Edit:**

It seems that I need an instance of `AppDelegate` to work with it. The question for me is how can I assure that this instance is available? E.g. through throwing an exception if it is not implemented?

Here is what you can do:

*AppDelegate*

```
public static new AppDelegate Self { get; private set; }

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    AppDelegate.Self = this;

    return true;
}

[Export ("YourMethod:")]
public void YourMethod (bool setVisible){
    // do something
}
```

*Some Class*

```
if(AppDelegate.Self.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("YourMethod:")))
{
    AppDelegate.Self.YourMethod (true);
}
```

You don't need to use `respondsToSelector`, you can use the other C#/.NET methods too (`HasMethod`, `HasProperty` from the linked threads) if you have the instance of `AppDelegate`. The question for me is how can I assure that `Self` is implemented in `AppDelegate`?

Yes, the compiler checks that for me, but I want to execute the method only if it is implemented. It should not be a necessity to implement it. It should also work without `YourMethod`.

Comment: Is a @try/catch solution suitable at all? It's a bit of a rough method, but should work.

Comment: @mylogon: This would be possible, but would it compile if I access a property which might not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. First you need two extension methods:

```
public static class GeneralExtensions
{
    public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
    }

    public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
    {
        var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
        return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
    } 
}
```

To check for a method you use

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.HasMethod("YourMethod")){
    // do something
}
```

To check for a property you use

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.HasProperty("Instance"))
    // do something
}
```

The idea came from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175878/iphone-access-a-property-value-from-appdelegate).

But this is not the end of the story. My final approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874561/426227).

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

I know that this is still Obj-C, but you should be able to easily get the C# equivalent.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"possibleMethod");
AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if([appDelegate respondsToSelector:selector]){
    [appDelegate selector];
}
```

Good luck

---

Firstly,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

You could try the below method using a `@try` block try test the selector.

```
    BOOL methodExists = YES;
    SEL yourVariable = NSSelectorFromString(@"possibleMethod");
    AppDelegate * ad = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];

    @try {
        [ad performSelector:yourVariable withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        methodExists = NO;
    }
    @finally {

        if (methodExists) {
            //Call method from selector
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition. I tried to translate your code into C#. Hereby I noticed that I need an actual instance of `AppDelegate`, where you can send the `performSelector` message. I edited my question to show you how I get access to the instance. But my main problem is still present: How can I assure that the property `Self` is implemented in the `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Apologies. For whatever reason I just noticed 'C#'. I'm not as familiar with that.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm also happy if you can provide solutions in Objective-C/Swift, because I can translate them most of the time. Are you able to access the `AppDelegate` in Objective-C at any time? Or how do you get the instance of it?

Comment: Ah. I will change my answer to suit then.